# how to remove the last digit in a list if the list contain number last number some were in the list

Tags: python

i need to remove a digit in the given list,But while executing this first digit is removed

python pycharm

```
l = [4, 2, 6, 4, 7]

l.remove(l[3])

print(l)
```

expected output:`[4, 2, 6, 7]`

But I get: `[2, 6, 4, 7]`

Comment: You should't be using remove for this. Try with `my_list.pop(list[4])`

Comment: Also avoid using `list` for a variable name, it masks the built-in method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has 3 methods to remove an element from python List.

You can read more about `list` [in here](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/lists/)

```py
list.pop(3)   # remove 4th element

del list(3)   # remove 4th element

list.remove(value1)  # remove element have value1 in list
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove an item from a list given an index, use `list().pop()` like so:

```py
l.pop(3)  # Remove the third element.
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using a direct `pop()` function if your list is dynamically generating because you don't know the `index` of elements.

The [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function adds a counter to an iterable.
So for each element in a cursor, a tuple is produced with `(counter, element)`.

```
list1 = [4, 2, 6, 4, 7]
new_list = []
for index,elm in enumerate(list1):
    if elm not in (list1[:index]):
        new_list.append(elm)

print(new_list)
```

O/P:

```
[4, 2, 6, 7]
```